SyntaxError: The requested module '@XXX' does not provide an export named 'YYY'
I'm facing this issue in Webstorm
SyntaxError: The requested module '@dydxprotocol/v4-client-js' does not provide an export named 'LocalWallet'
My code is very liminal:
import {LocalWallet} from "@dydxprotocol/v4-client-js";
I compile my code with npx tsx index.ts.
The dependency was added with npm i --save-dev @dydxprotocol/v4-client-js. I also tried it without the --save-devoption, it's the same.
Below are my package.json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@dydxprotocol/v4-client-js": "^1.13.0",
    "tsx": "^4.19.2",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  },
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "type": "module"
}

and tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "target": "es2022",
    "lib": ["es2022"],
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}


I know similar issues have been discussed already but I am really stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't see any file in the root of the repo to import the LocalWallet from. You should try getting it from the src folder like import {LocalWallet} from "@dydxprotocol/v4-client-js/src";

@Khopadi, LocalWallet must be directly imported from "@dydxprotocol/v4-client-js". That package's main entry point is defined here in the package.json, and the package defines no entry point at src. I tested your suggestion, and it broke the code.

Finally fixed it, I think it was coming from a misconfiguration of Webstorm. I followed the doc on Jetbrain's website. In particular I took the time to properly configure Language Services for TypeScript and run configuration, I use ts-node on the produced JS code.
There seems to be no need to use npx tsc --init, to generate the package.json and tsconfig.json one can simply create the files from the Project window.

There are two problems here:

tsconfig.json error: when module is set to NodeNext, moduleResolution must be set to NodeNext or left unset:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
  }
}

P.S. skipDefaultLibCheck is deprecated, so you can remove that option – since you have skipLibCheck set to true, tsc will skip all libs anyway.

node_modules missing type-dependency: To debug, I ran tsc with skipLibCheck set to false, and tsc complained to me about a missing downlevel type-dependency (ws). Once I installed @types/ws as a devDependency, the project successfully built:
npm i -D @types/ws




The above changes to your code resolve two crucial type errors and resulted in the project compiling successfully.
However, you mentioned Webstorm, which I'm not familiar with. It's possible that Webstorm's built-in type system may interact with your tsconfig and package.json in some unexpected way.
Let me know if you still run into any issues.
